# Unable to create key while signing my app

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to create a apk of the my app.I went through the docs and found out the procedure.I was First Instructed to go to my project folder and put in the command :

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 
10000 -alias key
```

But then i got a error that keytool wasn't a recognized command.I looked up online and found out the directory where my java is installed and then opened cmd in the folder where keytool was present.

The command was executed successfully and i got all the proceedings such as creating my keystore password and other personal details.

Towards the end , right after i put in the password for the key i get a error :

```
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~\key.jks (The system cannot 
find the path specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~\key.jks (The system cannot find the path 
specified)
         at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
         at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
         at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
         at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
         at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1144)
         at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:343)
         at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:336)
```

I should get a file named key.jks but that fails.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you should use Android Studio or IntelliJ Idea to create your keystore. There is a built-in solution for creating keys. It is much more easier than doing by hand.

Comment: @Gunhan the option under the build menu of build bundles /apk is disabled in my android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found what the real issue was.
My Java being installed in the C drive i needed administrators right to make changes in the folder.Sometimes your system might not allow you to store even after you try and run as administrator. Which is why i was prompted with the error saying :

```
 keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~\key.jks (The system cannot 
 find the path specified)
```

Which signifies that the command is unable to access and edit the contents of the folder.

Then i tried storing the key.jks file in my project folder but then i was prompted with a error that it was illegal option. I concurred that i shouldn't go so deep into the directory.

Finally i tried a simple path which was my D drive and the command looked something like :

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore D:/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 - 
alias key
```

This worked for me.Hope my answer helps.

Comment: It would probably have been even better to use `-keystore C:\users\kshitij\key.jks`

Comment: @RichardHeap could you state the reason for your advice.

Comment: That's the window equivalent of ~

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Example:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore **Your PC path** /key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

like this

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore /Users/sunnysaini/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

I hope above will work for you.

Here is another solution if you want to create signed apk

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("release.keystore")
        storePassword "******"
        keyAlias "******"
        keyPassword "******"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

You can also use android studio option to generate apk

> https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: As i mentioned in my question the key tool command is working , but finally i do not obtain a key.jks file and face the error.The alternate method that you have mentioned , seems insufficient since i do not know here to write that code.Also  in Android studio my option of  build bundles and apk under the build menu is disabled.